# Get data from eloquent relationship with pivot in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have 3 DB table.

*shows*

[image: Table with my shows]

*show_genres*

[image: Table with my genres]

*show_show_genre*

[image]

In my show model, i have:

```
public function genres()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\ShowGenre');
    }
```

So when i do:

```
$show=Show::find(1);
```

`$show->genres` give me collection with all genres that have show_id in shows_genres db.

I have also ShowGenre model where is all genres i have and i use.

Becouse i want to use sync for my genres, that names need to be in database.

But how can i find all shows that have genre id.

I couldn't find any way to get that list. Please help, thanks.

Edit:

[image: This is shows_genres db table]

Comment: which column refers to "strict" in genre table ?

Comment: genre_id column refers to "strict".

Comment: genre_id isn't a number : 1,2 .... ?

Comment: I added table results in question so you can see how i store that data.

Comment: @PooX thank you for noticing typo shows()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this other way around:

Have a model for Genre

your relationship method in Genre model should be

```
public function shows()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Show', 'shows_genres');
    }
```

belongsToMany accepts two parameters, model and pivot table name if not a standard name.

Your solution:

```
    //Get genre 'strict'
    //where could be followed by column name example:whereSlug, whereName
    $strictGenre = Genre::whereName('strict')->first();

    if($strictGenre)
    {
        //get shows of this genre
        $strictShows = $strictGenre->shows;
    }
```

Read manytomany relationships:

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
$show->genres()
    ->wherePivot('column', value)
    ->get();
```

> By default Pivot table name must be singular : show_genre  (without
>   plural s)

See [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Comment: The pivot table is derived from the alphabetical order of the related model names, so should be genre_show

Comment: That doesn't work, i try it. Please see my edited post again. I added more info.

Comment: Join me here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206631/get-data-from-eloquent-relationship-with-pivot-in-laravel

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have this relationship in your genres model

```
public function shows()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\Show', 'shows_genres', 'genre_id', 'show_id');
}
```

Then you can directly get all shows by genres id like this

```
$shows = Genre::find($id)->shows;
```